# Zend Framework $this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest() IE7/8

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, xmlhttprequest

I seem to have a problem with checking for AJAX requests in my controller when using IE7/8.

```
if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $do = 'the dance';
}
```

But `$do` never gets filled using Zends `isXmlHttpRequest()` ....

Can anyone help?

EDIT:
On the clientside I use jQuery to send the request

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success: fx.planer.callback
    });

ajax($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize());
```

Any clue why jQuery is missing the header?

Comment: How are you sending the requests?  Are you using a library like jQuery, or your own solution?

Comment: Nothing wrong with ZF here, what we need is your client-side code (javascript). Make sure `X-Requested-With` in the request header is set to `XmlHttpRequest`.

Comment: added the clientside code. Isn't jquery sending this header?

Comment: `$form.serialize()` seems to be the problem. The header is sent and Zend finds the request. But the data is empty.... sorry my fault

Comment: problem solved, client errors caused an empty form so `$do`actually had been filled. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

It will sound stupid but ...

1/ Does `if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())` behave the same ?

2/ How do you check that $do is not filled ? Did you try an echo inside the if ?

Comment: yes behaves the same. And works now, problem was empty values in checkboxes because of UI plugin for jquery...